# I'm trying to call a SOAP request using PHP

Tags: php, xml, soap, soapui

I'm trying to call a SOAP method using PHP.

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:bpm="http://bpmellat.co/" xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
   <soap:Header>
      <wsse:Security soap:mustUnderstand="true" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
         <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="Timestamp-8" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
            <wsu:Created>2014-05-08T16:02:38.053Z</wsu:Created>
            <wsu:Expires>2020-05-07T16:03:38.053Z</wsu:Expires>
         </wsu:Timestamp>
         <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-7" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
            <wsse:Username>username</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">password</wsse:Password>
            <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">D5L5sjDemfkf/bq5zn7DMA==</wsse:Nonce>
            <wsu:Created>2014-05-08T16:02:34.714Z</wsu:Created>
         </wsse:UsernameToken>
      </wsse:Security>
   </soap:Header>
   <soap:Body>
      <bpm:getTransactionByDate>
         <bpm:TerminalId>1461389</bpm:TerminalId>
         <bpm:FromDate>20130101</bpm:FromDate>
         <bpm:ToDate>20140808</bpm:ToDate>
      </bpm:getTransactionByDate>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

my code is :

```
$client = new SoapClient("http://bos.bpm.bankmellat.ir/backoffice/Services/bpm/TransactionService.asmx?wsdl",array("trace"=> 1, "exceptions" => 0));

$sh_param = array(
                'Username'    =>    'username',
                'Password'    =>    'password');
$headers = new SoapHeader('http://soapserver.example.com/webservices', 'UserCredentials', $sh_param);
$parameters = array('TerminalId'=>'124124','FromDate'=>'20140508','ToDate'=>'20140508');
$client->__soapCall("getTransactionByDate", $parameters, null,
                new SoapHeader('http://bpmellat.co/',
                               'Security',
                               $sh_param));
//...code goes here...

echo $client->getTransactionByDate($parameters)->getTransactionByDateResult;
//output debug info
var_dump($client->__getLastRequestHeaders());
print "<pre>";
print "Request :\n".htmlspecialchars($client->__getLastRequest()) ."\n";
print "Response:\n".htmlspecialchars($client->__getLastResponse())."\n";
print "</pre>";
```

but it not works , the request xml text works in soap ui but not working with php :(
please help me :( i can build this request with cURL but i want to impelementation it with SoapClient

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Can you pls tell us the error you are getting ??

Comment: error is with username password and UsernameToken and Timestamp

Comment: i could'nt passing value of timestamp and other variable to soap with soapvar or __call or... method of php :(